# Laravel 5 multiple "dashboard" route for admins and managers

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, middleware

(I have asked this question before, and did find a way around which worked for a while, but soon got out of hand. So now I am looking for a perfect solution to achieve this, the Laravel way.)

The problem is pretty simple, when admin goes to http://example.com/dashboard they should see the admin dashboard and when manager goes to the same link he should see the managers dashboard.

The way around that I used before was to call the `pagecontroller` and then depending on the user role call the relevant admin's or manager's dashboard controller.

```
    // ROUTES.php
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard');
        Route::get('users', 'PagesController@manageUsers');
    });

    // PagesController
        public function dashboard(){

           if($this->user->isAdmin()){
                return $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\dashboard')->index();
            }
           if($this->user->isManager()){
                   return $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\Manager\dashboard')->index();
                }
        }
```

Now the problem with this approach is that I can no longer call the middleware on the dashboard controller because the process doesn't involve calling the kernel.

I am pretty sure there must be a way to achieve such a basic feature, I would be really grateful if someone can sort this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason this isn't a Laravel default feature because it kinda goes counter to what routes are supposed to represent. In other words, this **isn't** the *Laravel Way*. Why not redirect the user depending on their role?

```
// ROUTES.php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', function() {
        if($this->user->isAdmin())
            return redirect('/dashboard/admin');
        if($this->user->isManager())
            return redirect('/dashboard/manager');

        return redirect('/home');
    });

    Route::get('dashboard/admin', 'Admin\dashboard@index');
    Route::get('dashboard/manage', 'Manager\dashboard@index');
    Route::get('users', 'PagesController@manageUsers');
});
```